# HTMLUnitDriver not entering information properly?

Tags: java, html, selenium, sendkeys

Using JAVA and SELENIUM LIBRARY:

I have a web automator that until now has worked flawlessly, using FirefoxDriver.
My code follows:

```
System.out.println("Creating new web driver");
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
System.out.println("Parsing CARD OFFICE PAGE\nAccessing webpage");
driver.get(myWebsite);

System.out.println("Setting login credentials");
WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("quickloginphrase"));
WebElement pw = driver.findElement(By.id("quickpassword"));

id.sendKeys(username);
pw.sendKeys(password);

System.out.println("Submitting credentials");
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
pw.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
System.out.println("Credentials submitted");
```

Before I started using HTMLUnitDriver, the program managed to login to the webpage, but now I get redirected to a "login failed" page. I think the pw or username are being entered improperly. Is there some subtle difference between FirefoxDriver and HTMLUnitDriver that I'm not aware of?

Comment: what kind of exception selenium throws?

Comment: Selenium does not throw any exception. It just redirects to the "login failed" page of the website.

Answer (score 0):

well, possibly you come across with the following issues here:
1)

```
pw.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

enter button handler is not handled properly
2)

```
id.sendKeys(username);
pw.sendKeys(password);
```

you are sending improper login-pass
 possible solution: try to press login button instean of pressing 'enter' key using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//....blablabla)).click();
```

---

so I provide you some code which I use to login properly and validation of successful login:

```
public void doAdminLogin() throws IOException {
        String curTitle=driver.getTitle();
        locatorFindingHandling("login.logininput", "login.admin.login");

        locatorFindingHandling("login.passinput", "login.admin.pass");

        locatorFindingHandling("login.loginbutton");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        String newTitle=driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertFalse(curTitle.equals(newTitle));

    }


public void locatorFindingHandling(String key, String key1) throws IOException {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(propertyKeysLoader(key))).sendKeys(propertyKeysLoader(key1));

    }
```

So as I've mentioned above try to investigate workaround. hope this works for you)

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why the ENTER button isn't working properly? I mean, it's logging in, just not correctly. :\

Comment: so if it is get logged in, then seems that enter button is handled ok. so the reason is probably be in your credentials login/pass? have you tried to debug the point which selenium fails on?

Comment: it doesn't fail. that's the thing. it just doesn't log in. im thinking it's not getting the credentials properly, but i can't SEE what it's doing (unlike when i use the firefoxdriver) so it's much harder to troubleshoot.

Comment: try to debug step by step so you can see etiher actual parameters ( login/pass)  passed to functions and  results returned by functions